# Does insert method of STL's set copy the value of passed objects?

Tags: c++, stl, insert, set

I've got such a C++ code (please don't ask why it looks so ugly ;) - you have to believe that because of further part of code it really has a sense):

```
IntSet temp;
SuperSet superSet;
for (uint i = 0; i < noItems; i++) {
        temp.insert(i);
        superSet.insert(temp);
        temp.clear();
}
```

It is intended for preparing  `noItems` sets of integers (`IntSet`, each containing one integer value) and inserting it to other set (`SuperSet`). Both sets are defined as follows:

```
typedef unsigned int DataType;
typedef std::set<DataType> IntSet;
typedef std::set<IntSet> SuperSet;
```

For me, this code shouldn't work as intended, because just after inserting `temp` to `superSet` I'm clearing the `temp`, and I found that `insert` is getting a reference as its argument: `pair<iterator,bool> insert ( const value_type& x );` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/insert/)

So, as the result of the code presented above, I should get a `SuperSet` containing only cleared `IntSet`'s. But "unfortunately" this code works - all `IntSet`'s are filled with proper values... So my question is - what does insert method from STL's set really do in its body? Does it simply copy objects that are passed to it by reference? And what is the difference in this method's behaviour between passing object or primitive types?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: "*Does it simply copy objects that are passed to it by reference?*" Yes. "*And what is the difference in this method's behaviour between passing object or primitive types?*" Less overhead -- one copy vs. two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert()` takes a reference argument to avoid the copy when passing the argument.  but it creates a copy when stores the item in the collection.  This is why the `clear()` can work in this case.  Also, this is true in both cases, so even though you are "reusing" `temp`, there will be separate copies in `superSet`

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration for `SuperSet` stores `IntSet` by value so the only way to insert a new element is to make a copy. Since a copy is made changes to the original `IntSet` will not be reflected in the copy.

This applies specifically to how you are passing `temp` to `superSet` though, in C++11 your usage becomes inefficient. By declaring a local variable to use as a temporary you prevent the use of move semantics by forcing a copy to be made.

```
SuperSet superSet;

for (DataType i = 0; i < noItems; i++)
{
    superSet.insert(IntSet(&i, &i + 1));
}
```

Discounting optimizations the compiler will create a temporary `IntSet` and initialize it with a single element. Because the compiler knows this is a temporary it can insert the value using the move constructor. This will do a shallow copy of the `IntSet` passed and reset it's values to a default state (i.e pointers to nullptr) resulting in a *move*.